# How to correctly implement a continuously refreshing progress bar in short width terminals?

Tags: c, terminal, carriage-return

I have to write a self-refreshing progress bar to the terminal - that denotes how much of a file has been copied so far. I tend to refresh the output every 1000 bytes or so. To refresh the screen, I have used the following outline:

```
printf("\r"); // clear previous output

// output is the progress bar, percent is an integer (0 to 100)
printf("%s %d file written", output, percent);
```

It works fine when the terminal is large. However, when the terminal is small, such that the entirety of the progress bar doesn't fit into it, the carriage return doesn't work. It only clears the visual single line, not the entire line. I wrote a sample program to demonstrate:

```
printf(
    "abcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghij"
    "abcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghijabcdefghi"
    "j");
printf("\rCHECK");
```

As you can see in the below image, since the terminal is small, only some part of the entire print output is deleted.

[image]

Putting multiple carriage returns has no effect.

Then, what is a good way to build such a continuously refreshing terminal output in C?

I also tried clear screen (`printf("\033[2J");`) but it didn't work for me. It tends to insert arbitrary number of whitespaces at the beginning of the output, see image for example:

[image]

Comment: The easy way out is to to only print the percentage. That's 4 characters (0% to 100%) so it's virtually impossible to run into the issue. The other way is to use a terminal control library (like ncurses.)

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the only way to tell if your message has wrapped to the next line of the terminal is to compare it to the terminal width (number of columns).  You can get that info by using terminfo(3)

```
#include <term.h>

int main() {
    setupterm(0, 1, 0);  /* default terminal setup from the TERM envvar */
```

Now you can access the global var `columns` to know how many columns there are on the terminal.  You can also use `putp(tigetstr("cuu1"));` to go up one line on the terminal.  So you can keep track of how long your status message is and figure out how far up you need to go to get back to the beginning of it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, when I try to compile this file, I get errors such as:

`/tmp/cc5zB4cg.o: In function 'main': cr.c:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to 'setupterm'; cr.c:(.text+0x31): undefined reference to 'tigetstr'; cr.c:(.text+0x39): undefined reference to 'putp'; collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Do I need to install something extra on Ubuntu 18.04 to use this file?

Comment: On Linux, you generally need to link with -lcurses to get the terminfo library stuff (its bundled with curses there).